Hide ServiceReference from referenced project
In my application I need to consume a third party a SOAP API.
For this purpose, I created a wrapper-project to encapsulate the SOAP-client generated from WSDL using dotnet-svcutil.
However, when I reference my wrapper-project, all of the resources from the service-reference in the wrapper-project becomes available in the referencing project.
My initial thought was edit the generated SOAP-client, making all of the classes internal.
But this lead to an issue with the XmlSerializer, which can only reflect public types.
Is there any other way to exclude/hide dependencies and service-references when referencing a project?
Thanks!

Have you tried adding <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences> to the csproj file?

Yes, it seems like it does not work on ServiceReferences.

When you view properties of the service reference, can you change it to be internal or private in there?

I already tried that, and it resulted in an error saying something like "There was an error reflecting type due to its protection level".
As I understand it, the client generated from the wsdl uses the XmlSerializer. Which created it's own assembly at runtime and therefore requires public access to members.

You could put the service reference into a child project then, that way you could disable transitive references up the chain.

I was hoping to avoid that. Thanks for your help though :) Do you mind adding your last comment as an answer so I can accept it?
